# "Failed to initialize the [add-in name] because the assembly [path to an add-in DLL file] does not exist" when launching Revit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revit-api

I've exhausted every resource possible and can not figure out what the issue is. Button images won't show & keep getting this message when I try to use the command.

> Failed to initialize the [add-in name] because the assembly [path to an add-in DLL file] does not exist

when launching Revit. Here's my code that I'm using.

```
   #region Namespaces
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Media;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture;
#endregion

namespace TpMechanical
{
    internal class App : IExternalApplication
    {
        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            String tabname = "TpMechanical";
            String panelname = "Tools";

            //Option 1

            BitmapImage b1Image = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_design3_fhY_icon.ico");
            BitmapImage b2Image = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_design3_fhY_icon.ico");
            BitmapImage b3Image = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_design3_fhY_icon.ico");

            //Option 2 

            //Bitmap b1Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Icon1.ico"));
            //Bitmap b2Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image1.jpg"));
            //Bitmap b3Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image2.bmp"));

            //Option 3 

            //BitmapImage b1Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack:application:,,,/TpMechanical/Resources/Icon1.ico"));
            //BitmapImage b2Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack:application:,,,/TpMechanical/Resources/Image1.jpg"));
            //BitmapImage b3Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack:application:,,,/TpMechanical/Resources/Image2.bmp"));



            a.CreateRibbonTab(tabname);
            var Tools = a.CreateRibbonPanel(tabname, panelname);
            var button1 = new PushButtonData("TpButton1", "Button1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command");
            button1.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button1.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
            var btn1 = Tools.AddItem(button1);
            button1.Image = b1Image; 

            var button2 = new PushButtonData("TpButton2", "Button2", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command2");
            button2.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button2.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
            button2.Image = b2Image;
   
            var button3 = new PushButtonData("TpButton3", "Button3", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command3");
            button3.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button3.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
            button3.Image = b3Image;
            
            Tools.AddStackedItems(button2, button3);
            

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;

        }

    }
}
```

I also have my manifest code below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RevitAddIns>
  <AddIn Type="Command">
    <Text>Command TpMechanical</Text>
    <Description>Some description for TpMechanical</Description>
    <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
    <Assembly>C:\My Revit- Custom Files\01-Revit 2021\Revit 2021 Repos\TpMechanical\bin\Debug\TpMechanical.dll</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>TpMechanical.Command</FullClassName>
    <ClientId>9EDCBEA6-942A-4D9A-932D-612B5E02DC9C</ClientId>
    <VendorId>com.typepad.thebuildingcoder</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>The Building Coder, http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
  <AddIn Type="Command">
    <Text>Command TpMechanical</Text>
    <Description>Some description for TpMechanical</Description>
    <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
    <Assembly>C:\My Revit- Custom Files\01-Revit 2021\Revit 2021 Repos\TpMechanical\bin\Debug\TpMechanical.dll</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>TpMechanical.Command2</FullClassName>
    <ClientId>1A164A1B-8B02-499A-8ADB-94A75557CD66</ClientId>
    <VendorId>com.typepad.thebuildingcoder</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>The Building Coder, http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
  <AddIn Type="Command">
    <Text>Command TpMechanical</Text>
    <Description>Some description for TpMechanical</Description>
    <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
    <Assembly>C:\My Revit- Custom Files\01-Revit 2021\Revit 2021 Repos\TpMechanical\bin\Debug\TpMechanical.dll</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>TpMechanical.Command3</FullClassName>
    <ClientId>C5CEC594-E407-40A8-B1B0-163DAA179CDD</ClientId>
    <VendorId>com.typepad.thebuildingcoder</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>The Building Coder, http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
  <AddIn Type="Application">
    <Name>Application TpMechanical</Name>
    <Assembly>C:\My Revit- Custom Files\01-Revit 2021\Revit 2021 Repos\TpMechanical\bin\Debug\TpMechanical.dll</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>TpMechanical.App</FullClassName>
    <ClientId>C12635D2-96E2-4DF4-B172-7BD9487F7AE9</ClientId>
    <VendorId>com.typepad.thebuildingcoder</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>The Building Coder, http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwFua.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading your question a third time over, it sounds as if your add-in is trying to reference a .NET assembly DLL that cannot be found when Revit tries to load it. Looking at the list of namespaces that you reference in your source code `using` statements, I see nothing but standard Autodesk Revit, Microsoft and .NET assemblies listed. So, they should all be present and accessible. Are you using anything else elsewhere in your code that is not obvious from that list? You might be able to use tools like `fuslogv` to analyse your add-in dependencies during load time, as suggested in the note on [Exploring Assembly Reference DLL Hell with Fuslogvw](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/05/revitlookup-update-fuslogvw-and-override-joins.html#6).

Comment: Looks like I'm getting some XAML Binding errors during debug. I added them to the original post.

Comment: Update: I got one of the buttons to work correctly after I put the full path for the assemblies. "C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2021\TpMechanical\bin\Debug\TpMechanical.dll"

Comment: Update: The IL decompiler did the trick! The full class name was pulling as a different name. Now I just have to figure out the button images and I'll be in a good spot to start on my own plugins.

Comment: Just solved my image issue. I changed the resources to embed & used the full path to the resources. Seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try again with a minimal one-liner external command and a minimal one-liner add-in manifest.

Follow these steps: [Revit developers guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html) [add-in registration](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_Add_in_Registration_html).

Ensure that Revit has read access to its `AddIns` folder.

Look at the [Hello world walkthrough](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Getting_Started_Walkthrough_Hello_World_html).

Do not say you exhausted all resources. That would take too long and probably exceed your life span. New resources are being added faster than you can consume them, so any attempt is doomed to fail.

The error message is telling you that the problem is not in the internal implementation code, but just in the basic registration.

Why do you add `internal` to the `IExternalApplication` implementation? Isn't that a contradiction? What does that mean?

Why do you use The Building Coder `VendorId`? That is incorrect. You are not The Building Coder.

Your `Assembly` path is complex and littered with spaces. In general, I try to avoid such complex paths and all spaces in folder names. I also prefer forward slashes to backward ones. You can omit the folder name entirely if you place the `DLL` in the same place as the add-in manifest in the `AddIns` folder.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I haven't looked at the hello world walkthrough but I'll give it a shot. I had started with the "my first revit plugin" from autodesk with your C# template. A lot of the code I left as is so it would be easier to find what went wrong when it did (including the VendorId/Description) strictly for testing purposes. But may have been trying to run before I learned to walk with this one. The only thing I'm not understanding is why the commands work fine in the addins but the buttons can't find them. I'll keep pushing forward until I figure this out but that part has me stumped.

Comment: The commands work and the buttons can't find them limits the possible problematic window significantly. that is very helpful. could be the full name of the `IExternalCommand` implementation class is different from what you expect. You can check it using an [IL decompiler](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=il+decompiler).

Answer (score 0):

I am being inundated with similar questions these days. Here is another similar one, a summary of a recent email thread:

[Q] I have dived into the Getting Started with Revit platform API, following the DevTV tutorial by Augusto Goncalves. None of my commands appear on the Revit UI > Add Ins > external commands.

[A] One thing you ought to read is the introductory section of the [Revit API developers guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html). It tells you exactly what to do to install and launch your add-in. It is shocking of that information is not clear and does not work in the tutorial, though. Thank you for bringing it up!

Installing a Revit add-in is really simple, but people run into difficulties like you describe anyway.

There are only two relevant components:

- Add-in manifest file `*.addin`
- .NET class library assembly `DLL`

These are the important steps:

- The DLL must implement `IExternalCommand`; that means, it must implement the `Execute` method.
- The add-in manifest must point to the DLL and must be placed in the Revit Add-Ins folder for Revit to find and load it.
- If the DLL and add-in manifest both reside in the Revit `AddIns` folder, the full DLL path can be omitted; otherwise it must be specified.

That is really all.

There are thousands of places explaining it; they all say the same thing.

Good luck and lots of fun with the Revit API :-)

[R] I have not had any luck since yesterday about my add-in not appearing in the Revit external commands.

I have carefully structured my code correctly. The add-in manifest file is pointing to my project `.dll` file. My project class explicitly implements the `IExternalCommand` interface and fires up the `Execute` method just fine.

I don't understand what the issue could be, not sure it could be the revit version am using am trying to figure out all possibilities.

[R2] I managed to debug my code. Kindly, ignore previous message.

The location of my manifest add-in file was locked. I guess that was done when my account was set up. The location needed permission to be accessed. This path:

- C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2022\

I utilised the try and catch exception to see the issue.

Once I gave access permission, the add-in file is now visible; it worked!